# Plugins for Calendar dates in Strip manner

Tags: jquery-plugins

Can anyone suggest me to have jQuery plugins for Calendar dates in strip manner?
Like this: [image]

Comment: Vote to close as opinion based

Comment: see the source html from where you have seen this. would give you a hint for the plugin.

Comment: @Saksham, thanks for your response. I check source html and it shows calendar-strip control but unable to find anywhere.

Comment: How about https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-strip